# How to POST list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, restsharp

I would like to post following JSON via API using Restsharp library

```
{
  "id" : "customerID",
  "name" : "customerName",
  "customKeys" : { 
    "dataA" : "{\"keyA\": \"valueA\", \"keyB\": \"valueB\"}",
    "dataB" : "{\"keyA\": \"valueA\", \"keyB\": \"valueB\"}"
  }
}
```

Actually i made following code which is creating Customer object and everything work correctly beside last fields customKeys....

```
public class Customer
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> customKeys { get; set; }
}

Customer customer = new Customer
{
    id = id,
    name = customerName,
    customKeys = ????????????????
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);

RestRequest request = newRestRequest("someEndpoint",Method.POST);

request.AddJsonBody(customer);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I just wanted to be sure which data type i should use in following case.
Should i use Dictionary of Dictionaries or just ListOfDictionaries ? Or maybe there is a better and easier way to make that POST call ?

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` seems fine, what's not working?

Comment: List<Dictionary<string, string>> well that one worked well for me i added also 
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer); 
     request.AddJsonBody(jsonString);

Answer (score 0):

You would use a Dictionary of Dictionaries if your Dictionaries have a special meaning besides just positional placement.
Otherwise, you would be better with a List of Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class CustomKeys
    {
    public string dataA { get; set; }
    public string dataB { get; set; }
    }

public class Customer 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<CustomKeys> customKeys { get; set; }
}

Customer customer = new Customer
{
    id = id,
    name = customerName,
    customKeys = new List<CustomKeys>()
    {
       dataA ="dataA",
       dataB ="dataB "
    };
};
```